# Programmatically enter edit mode on datagrid row

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

i have following request: items are added and removed from datagrid (WPF) with button click. When user adds new row (new item) in datagrid, I want to automatically enter edit mode on this new item. This would work if SelectionUnit would be Cell, but I would like it to be FullRow. I tried to change SelectionUnit to Cell before calling datagrig.BeginEdit() but it doesn't work.

Here's the code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgDatagrid"  Margin="20,20,3,3" CanUserSortColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding AllItems}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionUnit="FullRow"  SelectionMode="Single" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
    CanUserResizeRows="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First column name" MinWidth="160" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstColumn}"/>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Second column name" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Path=SecondColumn, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And background functionality:

```
private void AddNewItem()
{
    var newItem = new Item();
    AllItems.Add(newItem);
    dgDatagrid.ScrollIntoView(newItem );
    dgDatagrid.SelectedItem = newItem ;
    var selectedIndex = dgDatagrid.SelectedIndex;

    dgDatagrid.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.Cell;
    dgDatagrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(dgDatagrid.Items[selectedIndex], dgDatagrid.Columns[0]);
    dgDatagrid.BeginEdit();
    dgDatagrid.SelectionUnit = DataGridSelectionUnit.FullRow;
}
```